# Why is the catch parameter implicitly  final?

Tags: java, java-7

```
catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
    logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

here why is `ex` implicitly final? What is the use of making ex implicitly final?

Comment: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-February/000003.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's implicitly final because it does not make sense for you to change the object pointed to by `ex`, especially in this case where it could be either an `IOException` or an `SQLException`, and thus the (static) assignment typing would be difficult to figure out by the compiler.

Comment: the programmer should be allowed to change the object pointed to by ex.By changing the object pointed by ex i can do some other actions.This will not be possible if ex is made final

Comment: @Rekha you'll be allowed to if you don't use a Java7-style multi-catch syntax. In this case you can't assign because it cannot be type-safe.

Comment: can you elaborate why it can't be type safe

Comment: @Rekha because it could be either a `IOException`or an `SQLException`. The static type of `ex` isn't completely defined at compile-time (it can be either one), and is only known at runtime. At this stage, if you caught an `IOException` and assign an `SQLException` to `ex`, you'd break type safety.

Comment: @Rekha You can very much change the value pointed to by `ex`(if it's a mutable object, however changing a caught exception is a not a common thing to do) , what you cannot do is change what ex points to - and you don't need to either as you can just create a new local variable and deal with that instead of ex.

Comment: @Romain even if there is only one exception instead of two then also will the catch parameter be final.If there is only one exception and if the catch parameter is  not final,then i can point the exception object to some other object ,thus breaking the type safety.Can you explain this to me?

Comment: @Rekha If there's only one exception type, you can asisgn to it, since it's type is fully defined at compile-time, and thus it is type-safe (e.g. the compiler can be sure you're assigning an instance of the right class).