# Any plain simple explanation for a good reason to modify exception parameter ex in Java catch clause?

Tags: java, exception, final

After reading 2 sources and other stackoverflow threads,
I still could not get the idea why the exception parameter ex should be modifiable(any rare case suits the purpose can be an example answer), anyone could tell a good scenario/time to modify the ex parameter?
And what is the meaning in Java language spec. to say "effectively final"?

uni-catch clause mean only 1 exception is to be caught?

```
catch (IOException ex)
```

vs 
the starting from JAVE SE 1.7 new features for multi-catch like

```
catch (IOException|SQLException ex)
```

get more confusing after reading below posts...
anyone could give a simple straight forward explanation for this question.

[exception parameter of uni-catch may be effectively final?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732039/exception-parameter-of-uni-catch-may-be-effectively-final)

[Why is the catch parameter implicitly  final?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737257/why-is-the-catch-parameter-implicitly-final)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

Note: If a catch block handles more than one exception type, then the catch parameter is implicitly final. In this example, the catch parameter ex is final and therefore you cannot assign any values to it within the catch block.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4
...and an exception parameter of a multi-catch clause (§14.20). An exception parameter of a uni-catch clause is never implicitly declared final, but may be effectively final.

Comment: I can't think of one. **Why**?

Comment: The term "effectively final" is defined in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4).

Comment: Please ask only one question. And honestly: there are many documents out there explaining what "effectively final" is about, including examples. Why exactly do think that all these written descriptions are not working for you, but the next written description, written here, would be helpful then?

Answer (score 1):

For the part about modifying a caught exception:

1. That is actually not a common practice. You won't find many people advocating for it.
2. There might be situations where you have your own exception class, that has certain information. Maybe that information isn't known for the code throwing. But the code catching has it, and adds it to the exception object. To then log that exception, or rethrow it with "enriched" data.

Regarding the other points:

1. The fact that you now can do a multi catch has nothing to do with that. But obviously a multi catch makes it rather less interesting to modify the caught exception.
2. Effectively final means that the compiler can find out that a local variable isn't reassigned. The variable is final, but you didn't put that keyword in front of the declaration.